# Grid using loops

Tags: java

I'm making a program that creates a grid with a number of lines and columns specified by the user.
I want the output to look something like this:

Lines (2..10) ? 3

Columns (2..20)? 5

```
   |   |   |   |

---+---+---+---+---

   |   |   |   |

---+---+---+---+---

   |   |   |   |
```

But my program does this instead:

Lines (2..10) ? 3

Columns (2..20)? 5

```
   |   |   |   |

---+---+---+---+---

   |   |   |   |

---+---+---+---+---

   |   |   |   |

---+---+---+---+---
```

This is what the program looks like:

```
String[] vertical = new String[columns-1];
String[] horizontal = new String[columns];

do
{
    for(i = 0; i < vertical.length; ++i)
    {
        vertical[i] = ("   |");
        System.out.print(vertical[i]);
    }

    System.out.printf("%n");

    for(i = 1; i < columns; ++i)
    {
        horizontal[0] = ("---");
        horizontal[i] = ("+---");
    }

    if(horizontal.length > 0)
        System.out.print(horizontal[0]);

    for(int m = 1; m < horizontal.length; ++m)
        System.out.print(horizontal[m]);

    System.out.printf("%n");
    ++j;
} while (j <= lines - 1);
```

---

I know that I need to remove an horizontal line, the problem is that I don't know how to. And sorry for the bad formatting.

Comment: Please fix your code indentation.

Comment: Your mistake is obvious, you just have to print one line less horizontally, why don't you fix it?

Comment: 1) Stop rebuilding constant strings inside of a loop. 2) Stop using fixed size arrays for something that doesn't have to be fixed.  3) Use printf with the proper options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.... and hell yes, your code is awful..... sorry for that, but true fact

```
    String[] horizontal = new String[columns-1];
    String[] minusplus = new String[columns];

    int j = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < columns; ++i)
        {
            minusplus[0] = ("---");
            minusplus[i] = ("+---");
        }

    for(int i = 0; i < horizontal.length; ++i)
        {
            horizontal[i] = ("   |");
        }

    do
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < horizontal.length; ++i)
        {
            System.out.print(horizontal[i]);
        }

        System.out.printf("%n");


        if ( j < lines - 1 ){
        for(int m = 0; m < minusplus.length; ++m)
            System.out.print(minusplus[m]);
        }

        System.out.printf("%n");

        ++j;
    } while ( j < lines);
```

EDIT: Here you have a way better implementation:

```
int columns = 5;
int lines = 3;

    int j = 0;
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < columns - 1; i++) {
            System.out.print("   |");
        }

        System.out.printf("%n");

        if (j < lines - 1) {

            System.out.print("---");
            for (int i = 1; i < columns; i++) {
                System.out.print("+---");
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("%n");

        ++j;
    } while (j < lines);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping a beginner. Guess I still have a lot to learn.